# "sed" command to remove a line that match an exact string on first word

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm working in a small bash script. I need to remove an entire line that match an exact word in only the first word of the line.

That's how the text file looks:

```
John is a dumb
Maria is awesome
Toni and Maria are funny
```

I want to remove the just the second line.

Right now, I can match the exact word "maria" but it removes the third line too:

```
sed -i "/\b\(maria\)\b/d" file.txt
```

How to specify just the first word?

Thanks!

Comment: Anchor your pattern to the start of the line with `^`. [The Anchor Characters](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-2)

Comment: you can try `sed -i "/^maria\b/I d" file.txt` ..... `^` is start line and `I` for case insensitive

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It has a precise description of the goal, a sample dataset, and an own approach to reach the goal.

Comment: @RamboRamon thank you very much, I was really upset with that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you are looking for "maria" surrounded by a word boundary (represented by `\b`.) Instead look for "maria" preceded by the start of line (represented by `^`.) Note I've also removed unnecessary parentheses and added the `/I` flag, which will make the search case-insensitive. Your original wouldn't have matched "Maria".

```
sed -i "/^maria\b/Id" file.txt
```

Edit: fixed case insensitive flag to I instead of i!

Comment: It doens't work in ksh? If text has line as 'maria-d' then? doesn't work

Comment: ksh is a shell. sed is a program. They aren’t really related. I addressed the sample data in the question, but I’m sure in most languages the word boundary assertion matches hyphens.